# AFNetworking UIAlertView when in background and no network

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking to update location details to a server in the background (using significant location change).
Everything works fine, except when driving round and it attempts to upload to my server and my phone has no data signal, when I re-launch the application later it has UIAlertViews on the screen saying "The Internet connection appears to be offline."

I have done a search on my project for the string, but it doesn't exist. So where is it coming from?

I would like to stop this being displayed when the app is backgrounded.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message is passed to `[NSURLConnection connection:didFailWithError:]` when the Internet is offline.  I believe AFNetworking passes this to a failure code block or delegate callback depending on your implementation.  You have code somewhere to make a `UIAlertView` display text from an `NSError` object but that string isn't in your project so that's why you can't find it.

Comment: That makes sense thank you. Yes I show errors in UIAlertViews. Are you aware of any method to check if an app is backgrounded (visible) before showing a UIAlertView?

Comment: If it's just one line, `if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] != UIApplicationStateBackground) [myAlert show];` would do the trick.